# Alternativa3D, DistanceSortContainer class not found in v8

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

I'm trying to load a collada model using this example:

http://wiki.alternativaplatform.com/Loading_an_animating_a_Collada_model

but I can't found the class on the .swc pack:

***alternativa.engine3d.containers.DistanceSortContainer;***

It's has been replaced by another class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such class in A3D 8. You can simply addChild your loaded model to anything that is or extends Object3D. Also, [here](http://wiki.alternativaplatform.com/Alternativa_8_for_Dummies_Part_II) you can read how to load models using A3D 8.